# specify single version for multi module maven project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, version, quarkus

how to set single version for multi module maven project? I have got warning for define properties.
*'version' contains an expression but should be a constant.*
also, I used revision property and then nested module can't be run.

Comment: Please provide more details so that others can help you by identifying the issue in your code/configuration.